# Are "protected" and "public" visibilities useless for class fields?

Tags: java, oop, encapsulation

It is considered best practice for [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29) to use `private` fields with accessors (getters and setters), instead of `protected` and `public` fields.

So, by following this best practice, we never use `protected` and `public` anymore. Have they become useless, or else what are their use cases?

The only thing I can think of is for public `static final` attributes (i.e. class constants).

*Note: this is the case at least strongly in the Java world, but the question stands for all languages.*

Comment: I disagree with your premise.  There are legitimate reasons to expose a member variable to a subclass via `protected` visibility.

Comment: @Richard I'd be interested to know exactly *when* to use `protected` and still follow best practice/write good and beautiful code. I've used it in the past, but it never seemed like there was a very strong reason to do it, except than just because it was easier and I was implementing both the parent class and the subclasses.

Comment: @Matthieu In essence, the use of a protected field can always be replaced by a protected getter/setter + private field.

Comment: Agreed @assylias, but you'd have to convince me that this approach is more "beautiful" (which is a highly subjective quality).  I see it as adding complexity.

Comment: I agree and I have never used that syntax, i was just saying it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practices can change over time.
I can think in two use cases for public fields, both somehow controversial.
Adam Bien says [in this post](http://www.adam-bien.com/roller/abien/entry/value_object_vs_data_transfer) that if you are using a DTO, you may not use private + getter + setter but only public fields. This way you are sure that data is transported as is, without any changes. But in the same line he adds that this will cost you lots of meeting explaining why you do it that way...

Another use for non constant public fields is using public final fields (initialized in constructor) to ensure immutability. Making your classes like

```
public Person{
    public final String lastName;
    public final String firstName;
    public Person(String firstName, String lastName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

is some sort of a *new best practice*, advised in places like [codemonkeyism](http://codemonkeyism.com/generation-java-programming-style/).

But unless you are the absolute owner of the code and/or you can force new standards to be fulfilled, you should keep avoiding the use of public/protected fields...

Comment: Very interesting point of view regarding DTO. DTO classes are often just horrible to look at.

Answer (score 3):

In terms of internal fields?  Yes, they're useless in many cases.  (Sometimes `protected` is acceptable if you expect there to be subclasses, though.)  And `public static final` attributes are also perfectly okay.

That said, `public` and `protected` *methods* are absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

"Useless" is in the eye of the beholder. Some "best practices" are overrated:

Suppose you want the equivalent of a C-style struct, basically a methodless class that just holds a bunch of data. It's certainly more convenient and readable to just have a class with public fields than a class with a bunch of getters and setters.

Suppose you want access to a value that never changes (like an array's length) a `public final` field is perfect for that. Also, it's extremely common to have a "Constants" class which holds nothing but `public static final` fields. There are countless standard library classes with `public static final` fields. Actually, almost every time you want a public constant it's the thing to use.

`protected` fields are pretty rare though, AFAIK. You really need to be planning to have a subclass to have the foresight and the need to use `protected`.

Comment: "every time you want a public constant it's the thing to use" => depending on what the constant is, an enum might be a better choice.

Comment: Good point. Actually there are a bunch of uses of `public static final` in the standard libraries that might have looked nicer if they were enums.

Answer (score 1):

In engineering "best practice" means general guidelines. Using getters and setters is not best in all cases. For example, if you are creating a BST, then it is a lot simpler to declare the fields of the Node class public (i.e. data, left, right); the methods in the BST are then simpler to read and write. Again because direct access is much simpler in some instances, you may use protected to give direct access to subclasses while denying access to the public..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I still see a lot of `public static final` fields, which make sense to me - as they're constants. Apart from that (and some `protected` cases - but need always to be careful), I think it's very rare to see that (and you should have some good reasons I can't think of for making a field `public` and not `final` at least).

However, I also think that use of getter/setters should be limited to the minimum indispensable - I saw in the past people putting getters on every field - even when not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime there are internal constant which only allow subclass to use, then you might need `protected` modifier instead of creating getter for those constants.
This applied to fields that allow subclass directly access, which does not expose to outside.

Answer (score 0):

public, private, protected and package are not limited to fields.

There are a lot useful applications to be used on methods and constructors.

However, it will be inconsistent to try to limit fields only to scope private since java is not able to do so in the case of nested/inner classes.